# How to call bash function properly

Tags: bash, shell

I'm learning shell now and wrote small script for using functions:

```
#!/bin/bash

show_date () {
  date;
}

show_ls () {
  ls -la;
}

if [ hostname == "mbp" ]; then
  show_ls;
elif [ hostname == "joe" ]; then
  show_date;
fi
```

If I run it on hostname `mbp` it just exits with 0 and doesn't call 'show_ls' function. Any ideas?

Comment: That won't work if your hostname is "joe" either. `hostmame` needs to be executed. It won't execute inside the `if` condition that way. Try `$(hostname)` and read some of the shell documentation regarding scripts.

Comment: Thank you! It did the trick!

Comment: You don't need to call the external program `hostname`, `bash` already has a variable, use `$HOSTNAME`.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to create your own variable for hostname then use the following (a built-in [Bash variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Variables)).

```
#!/bin/bash
show_date () {
  date;
}

show_ls () {
  ls -la;
}

if [[ $HOSTNAME = "mbp" ]]; then
  show_ls;
elif [[ $HOSTNAME = "joe" ]]; then
  show_date;
fi
```

---

Actually you haven't mentioned your host's name (I am assuming you have to compare your server name in if condition, if this is the case then you have to create a variable named `hostname` and keep its value to command `hostname` and then do comparison). Try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
#!/bin/bash
hostname=$(hostname)

show_date () {
  date;
}

show_ls () {
  ls -la;
}

if [[ "$hostname" = "mbp" ]]; then
  show_ls;
elif [[ "$hostname" = "joe" ]]; then
  show_date;
fi
```

Comment: No, it's same exit 0 and no call for show_ls function.

Comment: @J.Parmes, so may be none of the conditions are getting true for your current host(because `hostname` command will take the current server's name) because when I kept my host name and checked it worked fine(keep the condition check values `mbp` and `joe` as per your server's name only whichever should be matched) for me, let me know.

Comment: @J.Parmes, yes I doubled check my posted code and it worked fine for me, please do let me know how it is going for you?

Comment: Why create your own `hostname` variable when `bash` already has `HOSTNAME` variable builtin?

Comment: @cdarke, I was trying to fix OP's script itself, let me add it my own solution which you mentioned too now.

Comment: @cdarke, I have added solution without variable too now.

Comment: It is generally better to use the more modern `hostname=$(hostname)` notation instead of using backticks around the command (```hostname=`hostname` ```).

Comment: it should be `if [[ $var = "string" ]]` (a single `=` instead of `==`, check `help [[`)

Answer (score -1):

The shell does not work like other programming languages. Barewords are literal strings, not variable references or subprogram calls or anything like that. The `hostname` in your `if` condition is therefore the literal string `hostname` and nothing else (you could put it in double quotes like you did `mbp` and `joe` and not change anything here; double quotes mainly serve to let you put spaces inside a string while having it stay a single value instead of two successive ones).

Anyway, since "hostname" is not the same string as either "mbp" or "joe", neither clause of the `if` gets executed.

If `hostname` is a variable (technically a "shell parameter") whose value you want to compare, you need to use `$hostname` to get that value. If it's a command whose output you want to compare, you need to use `$(hostname)` to get that output:

```
if [[ $hostname == mbp ]]; then
```

or

```
if [[ $(hostname) == mbp ]]; then
```